# Argument is of length 0, no NA's

Tags: r, na

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
         logentrytime ord_lat_dt0 ord_lat_dt1 ord_lat_dt2 ord_lat_dt3 ord_lat_dt4 ord_lat_dt5 ord_lat_dt6 ord_lat_dt7 ord_lat_dt8 ord_lat_dt9 ord_num0 ord_num1 ord_num2
1 2016-11-10 14:23:36           0           0           0           0           0           0  2016-02-12           0           0           0        0        0        0
2 2016-11-10 14:22:22           0           0           0           0           0           0  2016-02-12           0           0           0        0        0        0
3 2016-11-07 16:02:45           0           0           0           0           0           0  2016-02-12           0           0           0        0        0        0
4 2016-11-07 21:10:00           0           0           0           0           0           0  2016-02-12           0           0           0        0        0        0
5 2016-11-07 16:03:29           0           0           0           0           0           0  2016-02-12           0           0           0        0        0        0
6 2016-11-10 14:23:05           0           0           0           0           0           0  2016-02-12           0           0           0        0        0        0
```

Where ord_lat_dt columns are last purchase date of a customer. ord_lat_dt[0-9] were pulled from different database tables. Thus each row represents one customer, and their last order date will be indicated in one of the 9 columns.

I would like to merge these, but before I do, want to calculate "months_since_last_purchase" based on the date in each column.

Thus, I have converted the date columns into character strings, and am looping through using these functions:

```
elapsed_time <- function(end_date, start_date) {
  ed <- as.POSIXlt(end_date)
  sd <- as.POSIXlt(start_date)
  12 * (ed$year - sd$year) + (ed$mon - sd$mon)
}


convert_time <- function(data, column){
  for(i in seq(1,length(data$column))){
    if((data$column[i]!= "0") ==TRUE){
      data$column[i] <- elapsed_months(Sys.time(), as.Date(data$column[i], format="%Y/%m/%d"))
    }
  }
  return(data)
}


test1 <- convert_time(test2, ord_lat_dt0)
```

But I obtain the error

```
Error in if ((data$column[i] != "0") == TRUE) { : 
  argument is of length zero
```

I've also tried changing the if statement to check :

```
grepl("[-]", data$column[i])==FALSE)
```

But I obtain the same error.

Any ideas?

If you decide to down vote, please explain to me what is wrong with my question. I am trying to learn and would like to make sure I am asking correctly.

NOTE: I am having a different issue and have completely changed the question. Thus some of the comments below do not apply. Because of the down votes, I could not open a new question.

Comment: What `date-time` do you want to replace the `<NA>`'s with? `0` is not a `date-time` per-se.

Comment: I don't want to replace it with a date time object, is that a requirement? This is customer transaction data, and I basically just want a flag that indicates a particular customer does not have a value for this column.

Comment: That's what NA is for, what do you imagine the flag to be ?

Comment: why the down vote? I'm going to end up merging the columns with similar names, by summing across, which is why I would like to replace with 0's, and not NA's... and now I see what @aichao meant..

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that when you do `data_theme[is.na(data_theme)] <- 0`, NA in the date columns will be replaced. But date columns are in a POSIXct format, and if you try `as.POSIXct(0)`, it will through an error.

One solution could be to do it in two step. First replace NA from numeric column first, then do whatever you want with POSIXct values :

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  mutate_if("is.numeric", funs(if_else(is.na(.), 0, .))
```

Comment: I'm going to be aggregating the columns across based on the similar column names, which is why I would like a zero value in there. Whether it be a millisecond, a second, or no seconds (i.e. a zero), NA is not the flag that will work with what I am trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

You can only replace all NAs by the value 0 if all columns are numeric first. This could for instance be achieved by writing a little function to first convert a column to numeric if needed, and then replace the NAs. Using `lapply` you can loop over the columns, and make the resulting list of columns a data frame again afterwards.

```
f <- function(x) {
  x <- as.numeric(x)
  x[is.na(x)] <- 0
  x
}

data_theme <- as.data.frame(lapply(data_theme, f))
```

Of course, this will also convert any meaningful datetimes to numbers.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I understand how to change columns to numeric, my issue is, exactly what you mentioned, I need to keep the datetimes

Comment: A data frame column is a vector of values of the same type; you cannot mix. You'll have to either keep the NA, or fill in a meaningful datetime value for your purpose. The same `lapply` approach remains useful though, just change the contents of the function `f` to suit your needs (e.g. `if(is.numeric(x))`...).